# How to get *binary photo data* from (v1.0) Get Photo API?

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api

I would like to get user's photo and display it in the application. How can I do it? 
Get Photo API (http://graph.microsoft.io/GraphDocuments/api-reference/v1.0/api/photo_get.htm) returns the "photo" object (http://graph.microsoft.io/GraphDocuments/api-reference/v1.0/resources/photo.htm) which doesn't contain binary...any suggestion?
Thanks,
Raymond,

Comment: Please add some code to support :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the binary please use https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/photo/$value

Comment: More info/samples can be found here: https://graph.microsoft.io/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/profilephoto_get

Comment: It looks like the menu link in the documentation leads to the photo_get instead of profilephoto_get API. I created https://github.com/OfficeDev/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/23 to correct that.

Comment: Unfortunately the specified link doesn't provide you with much information regarding what to do with the response of the photo/$value endpoint. I included some more information in a blog post at http://blog.mastykarz.nl/office-365-groups-api/. It would be great if we could incorporate this information in the official documentation. I've submitted a related issue at https://github.com/OfficeDev/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/19.